# Combine Textudio profile and session files

Tags: texstudio

I am using Texmaker and have for different configurations for different projects. Differences are for example the usage of biber vs. bitex, draftmode or not, which pdfviewer, language etc.

Currently, for each project I have a corresponding session file (`.txss`) to load all the source files (`.tex`, `.cls`, `.sty`, `.bib`, etc.) and a profile file (`.txsprofile`) for the corresponding configurations.

As it's a bit tedious to always do open two files, would it be possible to define the (custom) `.txsprofile` that should be opened when a certain `.txss` is loaded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Loading a profile with a session is not supported in TeXstudio.

Some of the settings like compiler and bibliography utility to use can be directly configured in the main `.tex` using magic comments `% !TeX program = ...` and `% !BIB program = ...`. These directives are understood by many editors, not only TeXstudio. There a more refined configuration of the build process is also possible using `% !TeX TXS-program:XXX = ...` but that's specific to TeXstudio, of course.

For details see the [User Manual](http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/manual/current/usermanual_en.html#SECTION_TEXCOM).

Comment: That actually seems even better as it is compatible with multiple editors. Thanks!